# Identification of the directlua chunk where an error occurred

Tags: luatex, debugging

In the wiki page http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Writing_Lua_in_TeX there is a promising solution to identify between the different lua(TeX) chunks:

```
\directlua {<lua code>}
\directlua name {<name>} {<lua code>}
\directlua <number> {<lua code>}
```

But there is no example. When I add a number, 3, as suggested in the last syntax. There is no compilation error reported but the error message following a lua error is not different : I looked for the number 3 for the faulty chunk but I had the standard `:1` reference for the chunk.

How does it work ? Is there an equivalent for `luadirect`, `luaexec`, ... ?

Comment: This is pretty 'low level': I don't think it carries through to the wrappers such as `luacode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare these

```
\directlua name{luachunk}{
print(debug.traceback())
}

\directlua {
print(debug.traceback())
}



\bye
```

The first produces

```
stack traceback:
        [string "luachunk"]:1: in main chunk
```

showing the named chunk in the trace

The second show the default name.

```
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk
```

Latex (or the ltluatex.tex file for plain tex) has a `\newluachunkname` to offer a slightly highernlevel interface to this.

Comment: Perhaps add a numerical example? (You need something like `\directlua{lua.name[4] = "foobar"}\directlua 4 {print(debug.traceback())}` to see the effect.)